# [Spring security][CXF] Mixed up authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, cxf

I have a problem with Spring Security Authentication with one of my project.

Here is the technical architeture of my project :

- TIBCO BPM which expose web service (I don't have the ability to
  modify this part as it's a vendor
- bpm-wrapper-ws : CXF web services that simplify and expose some of
  the BPM web service call. Secured with Spring Security through : CAS,
  username token and basic authentication.

bpm-wrapper-ws can be called either by :

- an CAS authenticated user through a web app
- a program through a default usernametoken
- through the BPM. In this case, it's a little bit complex as I need to authenticate the user but the BPM can only handle WSS (with a default username). 
  So I authenticate the call with a WSS authentication and after that I set the authenticated user myself with a custom code.

Example :

```
public void completeWorkitemForProcess(@WebParam(name = "processId") String processId, @WebParam(name = "workItemName") String workItemName, @WebParam(name= "username") String username) {
  // Authenticated with a generic user
  // Setting the login of the user passed in the parameters of the method
  TibcoAuthenticationHolder.setLogin(username);

  final WorkItemSearchCriteria searchCriteria = new WorkItemSearchCriteria();
  searchCriteria.setProcessId(processId);
  searchCriteria.setWorkItemName(workItemName);
  searchCriteria.setFirstResult(0);
  searchCriteria.setMaxResults(1);

  final SearchResult<WorkItem> result = findWorkItems(userGuid, username, searchCriteria);
  if (result != null && result.getTotalRecords() == 1) {
      WorkItem workItem = result.getResult().get(0);
      if (workItem.getState() == WorkItemState.OFFERED) {
          workItem = openWorkitem(userGuid, workItem.getId());
      }

      // do the TIBCO BPM call (use ClientPasswordCallback and BpmAuthenticator)
      completeWorkitem(workItem);
  } else {
      if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
          LOGGER.debug("completeWorkitemForProcess - aucun workItem trouvé [username=" + username
                + ", processId=" + processId + ", workItemName=" + workItemName + "]");
      }
  }

  // Delete the authentication
  TibcoAuthenticationHolder.clear();
  SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

I had to add the following lines in order to be able to do a complete call to the BPM :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetClass"
    value="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="setStrategyName" />
  <property name="arguments">
      <list>
          <value>MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL</value>
      </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Apparently, the problem is that CXF creates a workqueue (as it's a new thread) in which without the lines above I don't have an authentication (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns null).

First question : am I right ?

My problem is that sometimes the authenticated user is mixed up with the different kind of authentication.
Example :

- user A call the method1 of the web service bpm-wrapper
- In the same time, user B call the method2 of the web service
  bpm-wrapper

I have a event collector that handle the BPM call and I see that : userB completes the method1 and userA complete the method2

Do you have any idea where my problem is ? And how to correct this ?

Regards,

Jérémy

ws-security-context.xml : Spring security configuration file

```
    <sec:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
        use-expressions="true">
        <sec:http-basic />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ACCES_APP')" />

        <sec:custom-filter ref="casAuthenticationFilter"
            position="CAS_FILTER" />
        <sec:custom-filter ref="usernameTokenAuthenticationFilter"
            after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        erase-credentials="false">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
        <sec:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="inMemoryUserService">
            <sec:password-encoder base64="true" ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass"
            value="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setStrategyName" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="usernameTokenAuthenticationFilter"
        class="com.agipi.spring.commons.security.wss.filter.UsernameTokenAuthenticationFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="casAuthenticationFilter"
        class="com.agipi.spring.commons.security.cas.filter.WebServiceCasAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
        <property name="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" ref="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" />
        <property name="proxyReceptorUrl" value="/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor" />
        <property name="authenticationDetailsSource">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.authentication.ServiceAuthenticationDetailsSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
        <property name="ticketValidator" ref="proxyTicketValidator" />
        <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only" />
        <property name="statelessTicketCache">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.EhCacheBasedTicketCache">
                <property name="cache">
                    <bean class="net.sf.ehcache.Cache" init-method="initialise"
                        destroy-method="dispose">
                        <constructor-arg value="casTickets" />
                        <constructor-arg value="50" />
                        <constructor-arg value="false" />
                        <constructor-arg value="false" />
                        <constructor-arg value="3600" />
                        <constructor-arg value="900" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyTicketValidator"
        class="com.agipi.spring.commons.security.cas.validator.ProxyTicketValidator">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${cas.url}" />
        <property name="proxyCallbackUrl" value="${proxy.callback.url}" />
        <property name="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" ref="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" />
        <property name="acceptAnyProxy" value="true" />
        <property name="customParameters">
            <util:map>
                <entry key="profil" value="${cas.profil}" />
                <entry key="ptr" value="j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor" />
            </util:map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyGrantingTicketStorage"
        class="org.jasig.cas.client.proxy.ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl" />

    <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
        <property name="service" value="${service.url}" />
        <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
        <property name="authenticateAllArtifacts" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="com.agipi.spring.commons.security.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDetailsClass"
            value="com.agipi.spring.commons.security.domain.DefaultUserDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="inMemoryUserService"
        class="com.agipi.spring.commons.security.service.impl.InMemoryUserDetailsServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="usersProps" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>service.pid</value>
                <value>fabric.zookeeper.pid</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder" />
```

TibcoAuthenticationHolder : Class that holds the login of the
   currently logged user (only used in the case of a soap message with
   WSS header) :

```
public class TibcoAuthenticationHolder {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> CONTEXT_HOLDER = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>();

    public static boolean hasLogin() {
        return StringUtils.isNotBlank(CONTEXT_HOLDER.get());
    }

    public static String getLogin() {
        return CONTEXT_HOLDER.get();
    }

    public static void setLogin(String login) {
        CONTEXT_HOLDER.set(login);
    }

    public static void clear() {
        CONTEXT_HOLDER.remove();
    }
}
```

BpmAuthenticator :Utility class that retun the currently authenticated user (login / password)

```
public String[] getCurrentCredentials() {
        String[] currentCredentials = null;

        // Hack permettant d'authentifier un utilisateur ayant appelé le service depuis un process BPM
        if (TibcoAuthenticationHolder.hasLogin()) {
            currentCredentials = new String[2];
            currentCredentials[0] = StringUtils.lowerCase(TibcoAuthenticationHolder.getLogin());
            currentCredentials[1] = globalPassword;
        } else {
            final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (authentication != null && springAuthentication) {
                if (authentication instanceof CasAuthenticationToken) {
                    currentCredentials = new String[2];
                    currentCredentials[0] = StringUtils.lowerCase(authentication.getName());
                    currentCredentials[1] = globalPassword;
                } else if (authentication instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
                    currentCredentials = new String[2];
                    currentCredentials[0] = StringUtils.lowerCase(authentication.getName());
                    currentCredentials[1] = globalPassword;
                }
            }
        }

        return currentCredentials;
    }
```

ws-standalone-context.xml : Global spring configuration file

```
<!-- Web services -->
<bean id="workItemService" class="com.agipi.bpm.wrapper.service.impl.WorkItemServiceImpl" />
<bean id="processService" class="com.agipi.bpm.wrapper.service.impl.ProcessServiceImpl" />
<bean id="orgModelService" class="com.agipi.bpm.wrapper.service.impl.OrgModelServiceImpl" />
<bean id="userService" class="com.agipi.bpm.wrapper.service.impl.UserServiceImpl" />

<!-- Intercepteur pour supprimer les headers WSS -->
<bean id="wssHeaderInterceptor" class="com.agipi.bpm.wrapper.util.WssHeaderInterceptor" />

<!-- JAX-WS Service Endpoint -->
<jaxws:endpoint id="workItemWs" implementor="#workItemService"
    address="${ws.workitem.url}">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="wssHeaderInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:dataBinding>
        <bean class="com.agipi.commons.xml.CustomJAXBDataBinding">
            <property name="basePackage" value="com.agipi.bpm" />
        </bean>
    </jaxws:dataBinding>
</jaxws:endpoint>

<jaxws:endpoint id="processWs" implementor="#processService"
    address="${ws.process.url}">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="wssHeaderInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:dataBinding>
        <bean class="com.agipi.commons.xml.CustomJAXBDataBinding">
            <property name="basePackage" value="com.agipi.bpm" />
        </bean>
    </jaxws:dataBinding>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

log_error.log : debug log file of a call from a CAS authenticated user (without MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL)

```
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-9] (ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl.java:save:94) Saving ProxyGrantingTicketIOU and ProxyGrantingTicket combo: [PGTIOU-4798-NWBAuWFslzNucvHilQxHaWKcteRmGgDwIto3USoFotyx9ZOjoZ, PGT-4797-P66p0r8rrg52Gas7tsaFCCtXdbrs5ABrf7Qq4AhweAzOcBOg1j]
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl.java:retrieve:83) Returned ProxyGrantingTicket of [PGT-4797-P66p0r8rrg52Gas7tsaFCCtXdbrs5ABrf7Qq4AhweAzOcBOg1j]
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (UsernameTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:doFilter:101) Header soapaction : "completeWorkitem"
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (ServletController.java:invokeDestination:244) Service http request on thread: Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-10,5,main]
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (AbstractHTTPDestination.java:invoke:230) Create a new message for processing
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (Headers.java:copyFromRequest:358) Request Headers: {Accept=[*/*], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8], host=[10.70.5.233:8082], pragma=[no-cache], SOAPAction=["completeWorkitem"], ticket=[PT-4796-nmG9YRBHG4zZt3wybQkn], transfer-encoding=[chunked], user-agent=[Apache CXF 2.7.14]}
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:add:206) Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@5b467a6b to phase pre-stream
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:outputChainToLog:687) Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@3279db7a was created. Current flow:
  receive [PolicyInInterceptor, AttachmentInInterceptor]
  pre-stream [CertConstraintsInterceptor]
  post-stream [StaxInInterceptor]
  read [WSDLGetInterceptor, ReadHeadersInterceptor, SoapActionInInterceptor, StartBodyInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WssHeaderInterceptor, MustUnderstandInterceptor]
  post-protocol [CheckFaultInterceptor, JAXBAttachmentSchemaValidationHack]
  unmarshal [DocLiteralInInterceptor, SoapHeaderInterceptor]
  pre-logical [OneWayProcessorInterceptor]
  post-logical [WrapperClassInInterceptor]
  pre-invoke [SwAInInterceptor, HolderInInterceptor]
  invoke [ServiceInvokerInterceptor]
  post-invoke [OutgoingChainInterceptor]

18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor@c93f9d
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor@275c67aa
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@5b467a6b
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor@2399de16
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:add:206) Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInEndingInterceptor@4d30cb64 to phase post-invoke
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:outputChainToLog:685) Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@3279db7a was modified. Current flow:
  receive [PolicyInInterceptor, AttachmentInInterceptor]
  pre-stream [CertConstraintsInterceptor]
  post-stream [StaxInInterceptor]
  read [WSDLGetInterceptor, ReadHeadersInterceptor, SoapActionInInterceptor, StartBodyInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WssHeaderInterceptor, MustUnderstandInterceptor]
  post-protocol [CheckFaultInterceptor, JAXBAttachmentSchemaValidationHack]
  unmarshal [DocLiteralInInterceptor, SoapHeaderInterceptor]
  pre-logical [OneWayProcessorInterceptor]
  post-logical [WrapperClassInInterceptor]
  pre-invoke [SwAInInterceptor, HolderInInterceptor]
  invoke [ServiceInvokerInterceptor]
  post-invoke [OutgoingChainInterceptor, StaxInEndingInterceptor]

18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetInterceptor@e3419f
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor@1f898b34
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapActionInInterceptor@4ac3889c
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.StartBodyInterceptor@7f121318
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor com.agipi.bpm.wrapper.util.WssHeaderInterceptor@47e92e2d
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.MustUnderstandInterceptor@3f1e58b6
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor@7ba3cdd4
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxb.attachment.JAXBAttachmentSchemaValidationHack@8e685a5
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor@6b3de01c
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderInterceptor@2b448545
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OneWayProcessorInterceptor@7ce87a47
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [http-bio-8082-exec-10] (ServletController.java:invokeDestination:253) Finished servicing http request on thread: Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-10,5,main]
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassInInterceptor@2b40b62
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.SwAInInterceptor@7a59f2ef
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderInInterceptor@7a575050
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor@3f201aec
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (ClientImpl.java:doInvoke:502) Invoke, operation info: [BindingOperationInfo: {http://services.brm.n2.tibco.com}completeWorkItem], params: [com.tibco.n2.brm.api.CompleteWorkItem@512f7220[workItemID=com.tibco.n2.brm.api.ManagedObjectID@1edbc84[version=7,id=1130],workItemPayload=com.tibco.n2.brm.api.WorkItemBody@1ef37f19[dataModel=com.tibco.n2.common.datamodel.DataModel@41d522f[inputs=[com.tibco.n2.common.datamodel.FieldType@35416116[simpleSpec=com.tibco.n2.common.datamodel.FieldType$SimpleSpec@20fe8dc5[value=[processName: 'processSouscriptionAN', pvmId: 'pvm:0a1213d', idActe: '43411'],length=<null>,decimal=<null>],complexSpec=<null>,name=refLog,type=String,optional=false,array=<null>]],outputs=[],inouts=[com.tibco.n2.common.datamodel.FieldType@50053e75[simpleSpec=<null>,complexSpec=com.tibco.n2.common.datamodel.FieldType$ComplexSpec@280d916f[value=[[value: null]],className=<null>],name=processData,type=Complex,optional=false,array=<null>]]]],getNextPiledItem=false]]
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (ClientImpl.java:setContext:711) set requestContext to message be{java.lang.reflect.Method=public abstract com.tibco.n2.brm.api.CompleteWorkItemResponse com.tibco.n2.brm.services.WorkItemManagementService.completeWorkItem(com.tibco.n2.brm.api.CompleteWorkItem) throws com.tibco.n2.brm.services.SecurityFault,com.tibco.n2.brm.services.WorkItemRescheduledFault,com.tibco.n2.brm.services.WorkItemAPIScriptCancelFault,com.tibco.n2.brm.services.InvalidVersionFault,com.tibco.n2.brm.services.InternalServiceFault,com.tibco.n2.brm.services.InvalidWorkItemFault,com.tibco.n2.brm.services.WorkItemFault, org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext.SCOPES={org.apache.cxf.message.Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS=APPLICATION}, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS=http://virbpm03dev.devlinuxagipi.local:8090/amxbpm/WorkItemManagementService}
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (ClientImpl.java:setupInterceptorChain:989) Interceptors contributed by bus: [org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyOutInterceptor@4a8b0c11]
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (ClientImpl.java:setupInterceptorChain:993) Interceptors contributed by client: [org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor@6ec55652]
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (ClientImpl.java:setupInterceptorChain:997) Interceptors contributed by endpoint: [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@3eaaee02, org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.SwAOutInterceptor@47efe572, org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor@56c0c443, org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderOutInterceptor@9953734]
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (ClientImpl.java:setupInterceptorChain:1001) Interceptors contributed by binding: [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor@235b3bd6, org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutInterceptor@3ab570bc, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor@d32608f, org.apache.cxf.interceptor.WrappedOutInterceptor@5dfc64c0, org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor@653aa974, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor@6e4b3297, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor@ae69013]
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (ClientImpl.java:setupInterceptorChain:1007) Interceptors contributed by databinding: []
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:outputChainToLog:687) Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@4fc7cacd was created. Current flow:
  setup [PolicyOutInterceptor]
  pre-logical [HolderOutInterceptor, SwAOutInterceptor, WrapperClassOutInterceptor, SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  post-logical [SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WSS4JOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [WrappedOutInterceptor, BareOutInterceptor]

18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyOutInterceptor@4a8b0c11
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderOutInterceptor@9953734
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (HolderOutInterceptor.java:handleMessage:57) op: [OperationInfo: {http://services.brm.n2.tibco.com}completeWorkItem]
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (HolderOutInterceptor.java:handleMessage:59) op.hasOutput(): true
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (HolderOutInterceptor.java:handleMessage:61) op.getOutput().size(): 1
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.SwAOutInterceptor@47efe572
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor@56c0c443
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor@d32608f
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor@6e4b3297
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@3eaaee02
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:add:206) Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor@49036b77 to phase prepare-send-ending
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:outputChainToLog:685) Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@4fc7cacd was modified. Current flow:
  setup [PolicyOutInterceptor]
  pre-logical [HolderOutInterceptor, SwAOutInterceptor, WrapperClassOutInterceptor, SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  post-logical [SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WSS4JOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [WrappedOutInterceptor, BareOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor@235b3bd6
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutInterceptor@3ab570bc
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:add:206) Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutEndingInterceptor@2be6e01e to phase pre-stream-ending
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:outputChainToLog:685) Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@4fc7cacd was modified. Current flow:
  setup [PolicyOutInterceptor]
  pre-logical [HolderOutInterceptor, SwAOutInterceptor, WrapperClassOutInterceptor, SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  post-logical [SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WSS4JOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [WrappedOutInterceptor, BareOutInterceptor]
  pre-stream-ending [StaxOutEndingInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor@6ec55652
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:add:206) Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor@3a9c384d to phase pre-protocol-ending
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:outputChainToLog:685) Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@4fc7cacd was modified. Current flow:
  setup [PolicyOutInterceptor]
  pre-logical [HolderOutInterceptor, SwAOutInterceptor, WrapperClassOutInterceptor, SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  post-logical [SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WSS4JOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [WrappedOutInterceptor, BareOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol-ending [SAAJOutEndingInterceptor]
  pre-stream-ending [StaxOutEndingInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:add:206) Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal@6634654a to phase post-protocol
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:outputChainToLog:685) Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@4fc7cacd was modified. Current flow:
  setup [PolicyOutInterceptor]
  pre-logical [HolderOutInterceptor, SwAOutInterceptor, WrapperClassOutInterceptor, SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  post-logical [SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WSS4JOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [WrappedOutInterceptor, BareOutInterceptor]
  post-protocol [WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal]
  pre-protocol-ending [SAAJOutEndingInterceptor]
  pre-stream-ending [StaxOutEndingInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor@ae69013
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:add:206) Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor@6dd141a0 to phase write-ending
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:outputChainToLog:685) Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@4fc7cacd was modified. Current flow:
  setup [PolicyOutInterceptor]
  pre-logical [HolderOutInterceptor, SwAOutInterceptor, WrapperClassOutInterceptor, SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  post-logical [SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WSS4JOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [WrappedOutInterceptor, BareOutInterceptor]
  post-protocol [WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal]
  write-ending [SoapOutEndingInterceptor]
  pre-protocol-ending [SAAJOutEndingInterceptor]
  pre-stream-ending [StaxOutEndingInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.WrappedOutInterceptor@5dfc64c0
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor@653aa974
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:doIntercept:269) Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal@6634654a
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:handleMessage:161) WSS4JOutInterceptor: enter handleMessage()
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:handleMessage:235) Action: 1
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:handleMessage:236) Actor: null
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal@6634654a
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor@653aa974
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.WrappedOutInterceptor@5dfc64c0
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor@ae69013
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor@6ec55652
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutInterceptor@3ab570bc
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor@235b3bd6
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@3eaaee02
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor@6e4b3297
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor@d32608f
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor@56c0c443
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.SwAOutInterceptor@47efe572
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderOutInterceptor@9953734
18:24:28 | [DEBUG] | [default-workqueue-2] (PhaseInterceptorChain.java:unwind:442) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyOutInterceptor@4a8b0c11
18:24:28 | [ WARN] | [default-workqueue-2] (LogUtils.java:doLog:452) Interceptor for {http://services.brm.n2.tibco.com}WorkItemManagementServiceService#{http://services.brm.n2.tibco.com}completeWorkItem has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Security processing failed.
```